# Non linear regression? Which model to use?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, ordinal-data, quadratic-form

For my analysis I am predicting an effect like the following (the IV being 'ideology' on a continuous scale).

I'm predicting a different effect for when it's low, middle or high. Unfortunately all I have seen so far are linear regressions that go in one direction.

Is linear regression still a good model to test this? If not, what are more suitable alternatives?

[image]

To offer a bit of a context: For my research, participants will have to read an article that either talks positive or negative about the colonial past of their country. In addition, we expect that their level of ideology (on a continuous scale) will have a moderator effect on their evaluation of colonial history.  Their evaluation is measured via multiple likert ratings (scale from 1-7). The different items were regrouped through a factor analysis. So:

```
DV: evaluation of colonial history
IV: article (positive, negative)
moderator: ideology
```

We suspect that participants react differently to the article based on their ideology. Participants with a high level of ideology will contest the article if it talks positive about the past (the past BEFORE the colonisation began). As a result, they will evaluate the colonial past HIGHER than in the situation where they read a negative article (and vice versa for the ones with a low ideology). However, we think that those with a mid-level of ideology (so those who are not strong in either direction and 'don't really care') are not as influenced by their ideology (who is a moderator effect), but will be more influenced by the article.

I know it's a bit of a complicated description, but I hope you can take the explanation like this to understand my statistical question.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your data. What are the green and blue lines on the graph? Do you only have 3 data points: low-medium-high? Maybe you many many "low" measurements and you know the mean for the "low" group, do you know the standard deviation for "low"?

Comment: Sure, I've added it under the initial question above. The context is a bit complicated to understand with this little information, so even if the hypothesis seems illogical, I hope it helps to understand the direction I want to go. I'm just wondering which model in need to use in SPSS (or process). Thank you for your time.

Comment: And for the data points: low-medium-high ideology: actually, it is a continuous variable and I want to treat it as such, but I'm not sure how else to express it. Is it necessary to split it?

Comment: if it is a continuous variable then your data should look like a scatter plot. Unless you only have 3 participants in your study

Comment: Normally in academic studies that use statistics they try to prove that a simple theory is not good enough to explain the data. A simple theory in your case might "Ideology has no effect on how people view an article", this is a theory you can test and disprove.

Comment: A more complicated theory is "Article rating depends linearly on ideology". Maybe you can disprove this theory and after that you can propose a more complicated theory which explains the data. Because you only have 3 data points it's likely that you don't have enough data to test anything more complicated than a linear relationship. Don't jump to assuming that the more complicated theory is correct, that requires a future study with more data to test.

Comment: What is "evaluation of colonial history"? How is that measured?

Comment: @Hugh Ok, so you would simply suggest a multiple regression? And test for an interaction between ideology and article?

Comment: @gung It's measured on a continuous scale. (the y axis on the graph)

Comment: Using what? How is it measured? Do you hold up the graph & have people point to some spot & then measure the location of the spot?

Comment: It was measured through multiple questions how people evaluate the colonial past (scale from 1-7). The different items were regrouped through a factor analysis.